# Polyomino that can tile itself

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, tiling

Find all polyomino $P$ such that we can tile $nP$ with $n^2$ copies of $P$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. ($nP$ is a polynomino similar to $P$ with scale factor $n$)
I conjecture that there are only $4$ types of such polynomino:
-The first trivial type is rectangle with integer side length.
-The second type is created by $3$ rectangles with integer side as follow:
[image]
The last two type is polyomino similar to one of two polyominoes below:
[image]
Is there any polyomino which not in the $4$ types above and satisfies that property? What if we replace polyomino by polyiamond, polyabolo, polycube,...? And as Timothy suggest, what if we allow all but finitely many $n$?
Here some link relate to this problem, but none has any attempt to solve it:
-[More rep-tile polyominoes](http://www.recmath.org/PolyPages/PolyPages/index.htm?RepO.htm)
-[The same question but with polygonal](https://www.wcupa.edu/sciences-mathematics/mathematics/vNitica/webRepTiles.aspx)
I think for too complex polyomino, combine copies of it would make either more complex polyomino or too simple polyomino, so it can't tile itself. So I guess we need some invariants which measure the complexity of polyomino. And $n=2$ may be the most important case.

Comment: The tetramino $T$ also works, for $4$ copies of it tile a 4x4 square, so 4x4x4 copies tile $8T$.

Comment: But the T-tetromino doesn't work for n=2.  The question is asking for tiles that work for all n.

Comment: (I understood the OP wants a family $\mathcal F_n$, for any given $n$. Possibly not what she wants, indeed)

Comment: You may want to additionally search for "rep-tile", the term for self-tiling shapes, and see "Tiling with polyominoes" by Solomon W. Golomb. By Theorem 4, a necessary condition is that the shape can cover at least one corner of its rectangular hull, which eliminates shapes like (e.g.) the x-pentomino.

Comment: @JohnS.Adair thank you. Let me check it.

Comment: The first example in http://www.recmath.org/PolyPages/PolyPages/index.htm?RepO.htm is a hexomino (two rows, aligned to the left, with 2 boxes in one of the rows and 4 rows in the other) that is reptile for all n.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch It's actually the second type. I've fixed it.

Comment: This is a nice conjecture!

Comment: I know that the so-called 'sphynx' polygon (formed from 6 equilateral triangles, hence not a polyomino) is rep-$k^2$ for all k. If that helps any.

Comment: @VeronicaPhan you remind me of Marjorie Rice.

Answer (score 20):

As [John S. Adair commented](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427281/polyomino-that-can-tile-itself#comment1098809_427281), the relevant keyword is **rep-tile**. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rep-tile#Multiple_and_variant_rep-tilings) provides a partial answer to your second question (shapes other than polyominoes); it cites a paper by Viorel Niţică, "Rep-tiles revisited," on pages 205–217 of *MASS Selecta: Teaching and Learning Advanced Undergraduate Mathematics* (AMS, 2003), which is devoted precisely to the question,

> Which polygonal rep-4 tiles are also rep-$k^2$ tiles for any $k\ge 2$?

However, Niţică does not show that there are no other examples. Many "near-misses" (which are rep-$k^2$ for all but finitely many $k$) may be found on [Andrew Clarke's webpage](http://www.recmath.org/PolyPages/PolyPages/index.htm?RepO.htm) (click on the picture at the top to view pentominoes, hexominoes, heptominoes, and higher-order polyominoes).

As far as I can tell, your conjecture about polyominoes that are rep-$k^2$ for all $k$ is open. I could not find any mention in either of the standard books on polyominoes (by Golomb and Martin).  Even a complete investigation of hexominoes is laborious, as one can see from the paper [Solving Rep-tile by Computers: Performance of Solvers and Analyses of Solutions](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.05184), by Banbara et al.

Comment: I wanted to ask Viorel Niţică if he had any more recent information, but then I learned that he [recently passed away](https://www.foundsferyo.com/obituaries/Viorel-Nitica?obId=21528497).